# Is it safe to update a workstation from WinXP to Win7 RC1?

Tags: windows-7

Has anyone tried doing an update from XP (as opposed to clean install)? This is for a workstation, but it's a user's primary workstation. Would you allow one of your users to do this?

Comment: I thought that there was no upgrade path from WinXP to Win7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned on the [Windows 7 blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/04/07/delivering-a-quality-upgrade-experience.aspx) the only supported upgrade path is from Windows Vista to Windows 7.

So your users would have to go XP->Vista->Win7, that's supported. However direct XP->Win7 is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not that good of an idea to use the user's primary workstation to test Win7 in a production environment. Even if the installation ends up working, the Windows itself might not be compatible with the required applications even with the XP mode.

So to answer the last question, I wouldn't allow this until the compatibility has been tested on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

We can answer this in a few days hours time ... unless someone happens to have grabbed it off BT .. (tsk tsk!) Or unless it's on MSDN already (i've not logged in to check)

Answer (score 0):

This link on the Windows 7 [XP Mode](http://community.winsupersite.com/blogs/paul/archive/2009/04/24/secret-no-more-revealing-virtual-windows-xp-for-windows-7.aspx) might be of some interest to help you decide. It may curb any issues with backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It has never been a good idea to upgrade windows. There is a lot of fluff that get's left behind. Specially skipping a OS version (Vista). But that said, It is one of the tested scenarios for Windows 7.  Your upgrade should work fine but no one would recommend it.

> Would you allow one of your users to do this?

Windows 7 is highly recommend upgrade. And with Windows 7 XP Mode - you can be assured that all your applications work fine. (Although I have not used XP mode with all my apps yet but I have worked on the MED-V technology of Microsoft which is used in XP Mode).